# Send a plain text email with mailjet

Tags: php, mailjet

Can anyone tell me how to send a plain text email to a specified recipient using the [mailjet api](https://www.mailjet.com/docs/api).

In the documentation all I can find are details on how to send emails using existing campaigns. I just want to send a message to a recipient I can specify.

Comment: Judging by the kind of service I would guess they either don't support it or you have to pay extra for transactional type emails.

Answer (score 0):

The best way of using Mailjet for transactional e-mails is to use the SMTP service, if you have the opportunity of customizing your local MTA to relay your e-mails trough Mailjet's SMTP servers.